# Subclass member initialization

Tags: c#, initialization, subclass, member

I've created two classes which replace the function of a `Point` (both variants) just to test them out, this is how I've created them:

Entity.cs:

```
namespace Xnagame
{

    class Player
    {

        public class float2
        {
            public float X { get; set; }
            public float Y { get; set; }
        }
        public class int2
        {
            public int X { get; set; }
            public int Y { get; set; }
        }
        public int2 Position { get; set; }
        public int angle { get; set; }
        public float speed { get; set; }
        public float2 velocity { get; set; }

        public Player CreatePlayer()
        {

            Position = new Player.int2();
            Player player = new Player();
            return player;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, both Point classes have a `X` and `Y` variable (I'm not sure if this is the way to set them up, if it isn't please tell me) and these classes are used in the position and velocity instances which are instantiated in the `CreatePlayer()` method.

Game1.cs:

```
namespace Xnagame
{
    public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
    {
        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
        private Texture2D playerimage;
        private Texture2D background;
        Player player = Player.CreatePlayer();
```

Now the problem is that when `CreatePlayer()` method tries to return it's "player" to the local player it gives the:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property `Xnagame.Player.CreatePlayer()`

error.

I also tried it with the new keyword and it gave me:

> `Xnagame.Player.CreatePlayer()` is a method but is used like a type.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms173115%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're using an instance method to create an instance.

You have two options:

1) Use a default constructor

```
class Player
{
    // Other subclasses, and properties.

    public Player()
    {
        // Note: I added the other instance value just for fun.
        Position = new Player.int2();
        velocity = new Player.float2();
    }
}
```

2) Use a static constructor method. (These are typically only used in a [singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).)

```
class Player
{
    // Other subclasses, and properties.

    public static Player CreatePlayer()
    {
        // Note how I created the instance variables for the player class,
        // and I used a notation called "object initalizer" to set those properties
        // when I create the Player instance.
        var p = new Player.int2();
        var v = new Player.float2();
        Player player = new Player()
        {
          velocity = v,
          Position = p
        };
        return player;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am unable to perform your first solution as it seems the variable does not exist in that scope.

Your second solution gives me a nullreferenceexception in the initialize sub where I attempt to set player.position.X = 100;

Comment: I just tested my code; it works as expected. If you were to copy and paste my code as it stands into your file (and you haven't modified your example code from your question), it should work as expected.

Comment: Ok, I did as you said and I'm still getting nullreferenceexception in my initialize sub, I'm beginning to think it's because int2 and float2's member variables are not initialized?

Comment: Wait, that's odd, I can set player.velocity.X to 100 in the CreatePlayer sub but in the Initialize sub it gives a nullreferenceexception...

EDIT: The player's velocity and position is still null even though I can set it in the CreatePlayer method, sigh.

Comment: Nevermind! I got it working, "Player player = Player.CreatePlayer();" was the last change I had to do, all your other code worked, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your `CreatePlayer` method is an *instance* method - in other words, it has to be called on an existing instance. You probably want to make it static:

```
public static Player CreatePlayer()
```

You should then remove the `Position = new Player.int2()` line - creating a player shouldn't change the location of an existing player, presumably.

(I'd also strongly recommend extracting your nested types to be immutable top-level structs, and renaming them to something like `Int32Position` and `SinglePosition` - although you may well find that the framework has something similar already. You should also make all your properties follow .NET naming conventions.)

Comment: This gives me a nullreferenceexception in the initialize sub where I attempt to set player.position.X = 100;

Comment: @Croccy: Well yes, if you stick with your current position type being a class, you'll need to initialize the newly-created player. However, I'd advise making the position a struct instead - and making it immutable. I've only tried to address the one problem in your question, along with some general advice... we're not going to walk you through every single issue until you've got a working app. You should try to solve the next problem yourself, posting a new question if necessary (*after* trying yourself though).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use static functions to  call directly from a class like this

```
public static Player CreatePlayer()
{
     //all the code
}
```

Comment: This gives me a nullreferenceexception here:

    Player player = Player.CreatePlayer();